# For concave 3D shape, how to classify outer-facing polygons?

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry

Given a set of 3D polygons forming a closed shape that may be concave, I need to determine which polygons form the outer skin of the shape.  The answer may be related to finding the concave hull (alpha shape) of the shape, in which case please elaborate, but if other methods exist, please mention them.  Note that I don't necessarily want to calculate an alpha shape; I'd be using it to then classify the existing polygons I have into inner and outer polygons.

For an example in 2D, in Sketchup, when you draw a concave polygon, and surround that with a bounding box slightly larger than the shape, you can pull the area between the shape and the bounding box into a 3D shape.  To do this, Sketchup must be determining which of the edges of the concave polygon are "outward facing", meaning reachable from the bounding box.  One solution that comes to mind is a "seed fill" algorithm used in paint bucket tools, which I might be able to use in 3 dimensions to find the outermost faces of the 3D shape.  But if another algorithm is used, I'd like to know what it is.

In addition, this is to be done in scala/java, so if there are libraries available to help, please mention them.

Comment: Is the geometry guaranteed to be 2-manifold, not self-intersecting etc?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the definition of 2-manifold, though it seems to be synonymous with a surface.  The geometry would reflect a real-world 3D object.  Individual polygons will not intersect each other except at their edges.

Comment: If the geometry is manifold, each edge will be shared by (exactly) two polygons. Otherwise the geometry is non-manifold. A "T" shaped surface, for instance, would be non-manifold, as the edges defining the "join" between the three arms of the "T" appear in three different polygons. If the geometry is guaranteed to be manifold the solution is a lot simpler...

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think this geometry will always be manifold then.  On the plus side, I'm guaranteed at least one polygon that I know is on the outer surface from the start.

Comment: However, I may be able to place the manifold restriction on the problem.  If so, what would the solution be?  One that I can think of is start with one outer polygon, and follow it over the surface to create the outer shell.  Is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would suggest for manifold geometries: start from any polygon on the outer surface and keep visiting neighbours (unvisited polygons that share edges) until you've traversed the whole surface. Many people have used this algorithm over the years, so I'm not sure if it has a specific name. I call it traversal, for what it's worth...

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible to traverse the mesh for non-manifold geometry?  There may be internal polygons that touch the outer surface.  I realize this would notably complicate the algorithm, but does such a variation of the algorithm exist?

Comment: Also, if you could post your previous comment as an answer, and ideally including some help with the non-manifold case, I can mark this as answered.